# Build Stage in Yaml fails

Tags: gitlab, yaml, webdeploy, runner

I installed a GitLab runner in a Build server and registered a runner for a Project I have in GitLab.

The Build Stage has the following in the first line:

- 'D:\scripts\NuGet\NuGet.exe restore %CI_PROJECT_DIR%%SOLUTION_FILE%'

I already verified %SOLUTION_FILE%' has the right value however I get the following error:

**Cannot locate a solution file.**

I already checked everything I could think of but I can't figure out why it can't find the solution file.

Comment: Does the user with which you are running gitlab-runner has proper access permission on this **solution file**. Please check.

Comment: Hi, I checked and the runner had the proper access to the solution.
I was able to fix by creating a powershell file with all the commands for build and deployment and calling it from yaml. For some reason having the commands in the yaml file didn't work.

Comment: Oh ok. Great. 